# How to add values in table based on existing record

Tags: sql-server

I want to add values in a table for particular employee based on existing value:

[image]

Here i want to add all values as it is except `pk_servicerecord_Id`, i want to increment this value by 1.

```
  INSERT INTO tbl (pk_Employee_ID,pk_ServiceRecord_ID,pk_Scale_ID, pk_Allowance_ID)
  SELECT pk_Employee_ID,(pk_ServiceRecord_ID+1) ,pk_Scale_ID, pk_Allowance_ID   
  FROM  tbl
```

// as i have tried somthing like this, but not workin

Comment: you could just make that column an `IDENTITY` type.  This would auto-increment by one on insert, no need to pass the new ID in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl 
  SELECT Max(pk_Employee_ID)+1 as ID,pk_ServiceRecord_ID,pk_Scale_ID, pk_Allowance_ID   
  FROM  tbl 
  GROUP BY pk_ServiceRecord_ID,pk_Scale_ID, pk_Allowance_ID
```

It will insert the record with `Max(pk_Employee_ID)+1` as `pk_Employee_ID`.

**OR**

```
INSERT INTO tbl 
  SELECT pk_Employee_ID+1 as ID,pk_ServiceRecord_ID,pk_Scale_ID, pk_Allowance_ID   
  FROM  tbl
```